# Difference between moment.toString() and moment.toISOString()

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have reading `moment.js` document, there have  a `moment.toISOString()` function for helps to formats a string to the *`ISO8601`* standard.

**`Also there have a another one reason for why we use moment.toISOString()`**

> `moment.toISOString()` function using for performance reasons.

I don't know `toISOString()` the performance best than `moment.toString()`.But only the result was difference while using `moment.toString()` and `moment.toISOString()`.

---

### So my question is.

- Why we should use  `moment.toISOString()`? for ***performance*** reasons?
- And what is the difference between `moment.toISOString()` and `moment.toString()`?

Comment: *"From version 2.8.4 the **native** `Date.prototype.toISOString` is used if available, for performance reasons"* (Native functions, being built-in at the language level are more performant)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can give a look directly in momentJS source code for such issue :). 
[Here it is](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/moment/format.js).

```
export function toString () {
    return this.clone().locale('en').format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ');
}

export function toISOString () {
    var m = this.clone().utc();
    if (0 < m.year() && m.year() <= 9999) {
        if ('function' === typeof Date.prototype.toISOString) {
            // native implementation is ~50x faster, use it when we can
            return this.toDate().toISOString();
        } else {
            return formatMoment(m, 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]');
        }
    } else {
        return formatMoment(m, 'YYYYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]');
    }
}
```

- `toString` use `.locale('en').format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ')` which is momentJS source code, executed in Javascript
- `toISOString()` use javascript Date object (`this.toDate().toISOString();`) which is compile and managed by your browser.

> Native implementation is ~50x faster, use it when we can

However, I think such difference is not relevant for a most projects, but now you know. ;)

Comment: Yup, that's really nice. now i  understood the difference between that. but i want to know the performance details.

Comment: `toString()` excute only one line, but `toISOString()` execute more lines, then how to `toISOString()` is better performance than `toString()`??

Comment: One is executed in Javascript inside your browser, the other is executed BY your browser in native language which is 50x faster. In this case, Javascript is interpreted. You can see details about interpreted langage on wikipedia :D https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language

Comment: Also good information here about toISOString in moment documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/